# HLSL: Unitys Vector3.RotateTowards(...)

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, rotation, hlsl, angle

I need to rotate a direction vector towards another with a maximum angle in a compute shader, just like the Vector3.RotateTowards(from, to, maxAngle, 0) function does. This needs to happen inside the compute shader, since I cannot send the needed values from and to the GPU for performance reasons. Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from a combination of [this post on the Unity forums by **vc1001**](https://forum.unity.com/threads/need-to-write-my-own-vector3-rotatetowards.155024/#post-5385117) and [this shadertoy entry by **demofox**](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4sV3zt). I haven't tested this and it has been a while since I've done HLSL/cg coding, sop lease let me know if there are bugs--especially syntax errors.

```
float3 slerp(float3 current, float3 target, float maxAngle)
{
    // Dot product - the cosine of the angle between 2 vectors.
    float dot = dot(current, target);     

    // Clamp it to be in the range of Acos()
    // This may be unnecessary, but floating point
    // precision can be a fickle mistress.
    dot = clamp(dot, -1, 1);

    // Acos(dot) returns the angle between start and end,
    // And multiplying that by percent returns the angle between
    // start and the final result.
    float delta = acos(dot);
    float theta = min(1.0f, maxAngle / delta);

    float3 relativeVec = normalize(target - current*dot); // Orthonormal basis

    float3 slerped = ((start*cos(theta)) + (relativeVec*sin(theta)));
}
```